# Reputation limit per question?

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/21061) and happened to click through to the user's profile, and what I saw surprised me somewhat. The answer is to a fairly basic JavaScript question which obviously quite a lot of people have found useful. It's got quite a lot of upvotes (4377) currently which isn't overly surprising in itself. What is surprising is the affect that this has had on this individuals reputation.

*I should note at this point, I don't want to necessarily focus on this user, it's more about the principle.*

With fairly few answers/questions (31 in total) this user has a massive reputation, full access to all the reputation gained moderator tools, etc. with actually quite a small contribution to the community. This makes me feel like there's something broken. I'm not sure a single question/answer should be able to drive so much reputation and made me wonder if there should be a cap on the reputation that can be gained from a single question.

Normally I find high voted answers tend to get turned into a community wiki, but with this being such a simple answer I guess it's not really warranted much editing.

Comment: There is a reputation limit for upvotes: 200 per day

Comment: @Ferrybig there is indeed. But that doesn't help with a slow voted question that receives a lot of votes.

Comment: Did indeed. But there is indeed a 200 cap per day, so this user garnered his upvotes and rep from the post over a long time, signaling that it has been useful for many a programmer out there over a long time.

Comment: @Magisch yeah, which I'm not disagreeing with. However reputation is used as `trust` on StackOverflow, not just showing how useful something was but giving you more privileges on the site some of which could be abused. If all that trust is obtained from a single, fairly simple, early on answer - then is that `trust` warranted?

Comment: What extra trust has he really got? The ability to close vote etc. It's not like he's a mod. Whether he does it through one good question (over 5 years) or a couple of thousand isn't really relevant.

Comment: Sure, this is not exactly what rep is supposed to represent.  But scoring a hole-in-one like that is very rare.  And the usual outcome is that the poster loses all motivation to interact with SO again :)  Like this guy did.  Exceptions are exceptional.

Comment: @gnat Thanks - my search didn't return that question, but agree that its a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You're implying that earning all this from one question is less legitimate than someone with lots of activity. That just isn't the case.

1. The answer is **5 years old**. There are lots of old questions and answers that are highly upvoted.
2. Earning 4300+ upvotes is not a small feat, let alone for one answer
3. There's a [reputation cap from upvotes of 200 per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it).

Earned rep is earned rep.

Comment: Indeed - that's exactly what I was challenging. I think of it this way - if I were interviewing someone and they gave me 1 good answer would I hire them? Or would I insist on asking them some more questions regardless of how good their answer is?

Comment: @Ian: I would hope that you wouldn't hire someone based on a number. Rep points should not be mistaken as some kind of objective value measure.

Comment: @NicolBolas It was an analogy - I'm not referring to reputation at all in that example. I'm referring to how many questions you'd need to ask someone to judge their ability.

Comment: @Ian: And my point is that your analogy is false because rep points are *not* a means to "judge their ability".

Comment: Yes, earning a huge reputation from one question/answer is not good for community. It is usually elementary questions which get upvoted and then incompetent person gets moderator privileges. At the same time, if we would have a threshold for reputation that one can get for one question, people will be motivated to answer more questions.